# How to determine if a resource exist in solution?

Tags: c#, resources

I have alot of images, added as resource (Build Action = Resource). Before I want to use those images, I would like to check if they exist as a resource, if they do not exist, then I will need to use a default image.

So, how can I check if an image resource exists in my project/solution?

Thanks!

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6e2cb620-14c5-4996-9864-d43e6de5d665/how-to-test-if-a-wpf-resource-exists-from-its-pack-uri?forum=wpf

Comment: Do you know they names you expect?

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Comment: Yes thank you, I used Nikhil's solution works for me :)

Answer (score 3):

If you know the names of the resources in your resource file `Resource1` you can test them like this:

```
List<string> expectedResources = new List<string>() { "_1", "_2", "404", "_3" };    
foreach (string s in expectedResources )
{
    var r = Resource1.ResourceManager.GetObject(s);
    if (r == null) Console.WriteLine("Not Found: " + s);
    else if (r is Bitmap) ((Bitmap) r).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Be careful, this is nasty when GetObject() returns big bitmaps that need to be disposed.  It usually does.

Comment: @Hans, thank for the hint! I had a `Dispose` in my original code but then thought the `GetObject()` wouldn't put it onto the GDI heap..but I guess you are right, where else should it go? Hm, the compiler can't know the object type yet, can it? Is it  better now?